# Why do I need to set cookie if session_start automatically does it?

Tags: php, session, cookies

Why do I need to manually `setcookie()` for a website to remember me by if `session_start()` automatically does so to produce the cookie variable `$_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'=>'xy362fgtw783hnjm']`. I believe this cookie variable is long term and the website site would recognize me when I return. No???

Comment: Who told you to manually set it?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid ahah you totally made my day !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

session_start() writes the PHPSESSID cookie, which is the session identifier. You don't need to (nor should) set the PHPSESSID cookie with setcookie().

setcookie() can be used to create other cookies with different values (to track information) not necessarily related to the session. setcookie() allows you to create persistent cookies that will be kept by the browser after relaunch (depending on the parameters of the setcookie() call).
Cookies are typically used for advertisement tracking.